# AppDomainUnloadedException when TFS is cloning git repos for a build

Tags: c#, git, tfs, build

Suddenly, when queuing builds in TFS based on a git team project, I get the following stack trace.

> Exception Message: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. (type
>   AppDomainUnloadedException) Exception Stack Trace:  Server stack
>   trace:     at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_clone(RepositorySafeHandle& repo,
>   String origin_url, FilePath workdir_path, GitCloneOptions& opts)    at
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir,
>   GitCloneOptions& opts)    at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String
>   sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitClone.GetRepository(String
>   repositoryUrl, String workingFolder, Boolean checkoutSubmodules)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message
>   reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)    at System.Func`4.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitRepositoryBase.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

I changed nothing for this to happend, googling so far I found info about it perhaps being macafee, but we dont use that on our build agent.

- Using an on-premises build server
- Normal TFS team projects build as expected

Comment: Which version of TFS? Which of the updates has been installed on it?

Comment: Version 14.0.22824.0

Comment: No updates have been made in between the builds

Comment: Please upgrade to Release Candidate 2 of TFS 2015 before continuing. Make sure you have a backup of your current database and keep it, as there are known issues that can cause dataloss on older preview and release candidates. Your TFS should be at least 14.0.23102.0 tfs2015.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by restarting the server - not sure how I didn't think of that.